# Ошибка Inconvertible types, после c# не понимаю как работать с большими числами

Tags: java

Ошибка Inconvertible types, после c# не понимаю как работать с большими числами, что делать?

```
  Integer M = (Integer)Math.pow(2, 32);
```

Answer (score 0):

Либо работайте с примитивами

```
int m = (int) Math.pow(2, 32);
```

либо используйте соответствующие методы обёрток

```
Integer m = Double.valueOf(Math.pow(2, 32)).intValue();
```

Comment: В Java беда с тем, что все типы знаковые. это не всегда удобно. если хотите работать с очень большими целыми используйте BigInteger.         **BigInteger c;
        c = BigInteger.valueOf(2);
        c = c.shiftLeft(32);**